# How do I set up WHM/cPanel to back up to GitHub?

Tags: backups, github, git

I've been motivated to start using GitHub because a potential employer wants to see my source code, but I'm finding the process of committing the files manually from my computer after downloading them to be a bit inefficient. Is it possible to have git running on my VPS to periodically or by command push select directories to a git repository?

I'm running WHM 11.52.2 on CentOS 6.7.

Alternatively, can anyone recommend a decent workflow for keeping live, local and remote backups in sync (without having multiple local copies)?

Comment: This is not something that is built into cPanel, you would have to do it via SSH i.e a cron job that goes a `git push` daily.

Comment: @SimonHayter Actually git is built into cPanel as of version 11.36 (my version is 11.52.2.4). So I know it would be executed by a cron job or something similar, but what to put in it I have no idea.

Comment: @SimonHayter Sorry I may have misinterpreted your comment about it being built as referring to git rather than the functionality, and it's too late to edit it. :|

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to put everything on your website into `git`.  Modify the files locally on your home machine.   When you are ready to publish, push them to github and push them to your website over ssh.   Here is a tutorial that walks you through cloning your git repository over SSH: https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/siteground-git/clone-git-repository.htm

The only caveat is that if you have sensitive data (like passwords) in any of your code, you will need to remove them before moving everything to git.   I usually store passwords in configuration files outside of the git repository and have the code read them from a known location.